# xml's generated in /var/log/layout

Tags: layout, xml

I have noticed in my /var/log/layout.log

015-04-26T15:23:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): index layout is dumped to var/log/layout/553d02d429a79.xml

2015-04-26T15:23:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): index layout is dumped to var/log/layout/553d02f50654b.xml

2015-04-26T15:24:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): index layout is dumped to var/log/layout/553d031578d24.xml

and so on...

These leads to the generation of hundreds of thousands of .xml's in my /var/log/layout which occupy a lot of hard drive space. Does anyone why are these xml's generated?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably one of your extensions writing them. No one would know the purpose of those generated XML files unless they know the content, which you haven't supplied.

On your entire Magento installation, do an exact string search for `var/log/layout` or `log/layout`. It will likely give you some hits, and that will be the code responsible for writing those files. If you don't get any hits, you have the save path in the database, or the path is constructed via code, which you'll have to figure out how to find.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It appears this was responsible for it Mage::helper('/debug')->logLayout('index');